# Paper.js, gap between cursor and canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawing, coordinates, paperjs

I am trying to build a simple drawing app with Paper.js. I can draw with the mouse  but I have a gap between the cursor and the line drawn on the canvas.

I have realised that the navigation menu on top of the webpage is pushing down the cursor (100px) I assume that the mouse coordinates are taken from top-left (0-0) of the window and the same coordinates are used on the canvas which measured these points from its own top-left corner (see the screenshot). I have tried setting the canvas position to absolute, which helps to get it to the top left corer, but I need it in the center of the window.

How could I fix this?

Thanks!

[image]

script:

```
...
    var doc = $(document),
            win = $(window),
            canvas = $('#paper'),
            ctx = canvas[0].getContext('2d')

    doc.on('mousemove',function(e){
            if($.now() - lastEmit > 30){
                socket.emit('mousemove',{
                    'x': e.pageX,
                    'y': e.pageY,
                    'drawing': drawing,
                    'id': id                
                });

                lastEmit = $.now();
            }

            // Draw a line for the current user's movement, as it is
            // not received in the socket.on('moving') event above
            // (because he only broadcats (not receiving))

            if(drawing){

                drawLine(prev.x, prev.y, e.pageX, e.pageY);

                prev.x = e.pageX;
                prev.y = e.pageY;
            }
        });




        function drawLine(fromx, fromy, tox, toy){
            console.log(fromy + ' ' + toy);

            ctx.moveTo(fromx, fromy);
            ctx.lineTo(tox, toy);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
```

Comment: Your script is using pure JavaScript/DOM code; I don't see any use of paperjs. I suspect the problem is in what (x, y) position you're using from the event. Unless the canvas and the whole document are the same then pageX and pageY will be offset. You need to translate the coordinates to the canvas coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can repro your issue by using an early version of paperjs - notably this version is the one on jsfiddle. I see the lines offset the way you do with v 0.22 and then correctly rendered with version 0.9.25. Here's my code:

```
<!-- fails -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.22/paper.js'></script>

<!-- works --> <!--
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.9.25/paper-full.js'></script>
-->

<style type='text/css'>
    #canvas1{
        height: 400px;
        width: 400px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    paper.install(window);

    window.onload = function() {
        paper.setup('canvas1');
        var path = new Path();
        var tool = new Tool();
        path.strokeColor = 'black';
        tool.onMouseMove = function(event) {
            path.add(event.point);
        }

    }
</script>
```